# PHP Imagick Gives black and white for some pdf and colors for some pdf

Tags: php, drupal, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagick

It's random or i think it's pdf with a bigger size than 1mb
it sometimes output the thumbnail as color and sometimes as black and white

[image: Black and White] [image]

Here's my code

```
public function convertPdfToImage($_pdf) {

    if(file_prepare_directory($this->thumbnailDirectory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
      try {
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $thumbFileName = $date->getTimestamp() . '.png';
        $imagick = new Imagick();
        $imagick->setResolution(50,50);
        $imagick->readImage($_pdf);
        $imagick->setIteratorIndex(0);
        $imagick->setImageFormat('png');
        $thumbFile = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($this->thumbnailDirectory . '/' . $thumbFileName);
        if($imagick->writeImage($thumbFile)) {
          return $this->thumbnailDirectory . '/' . $thumbFileName;
        }else{
          \Drupal::logger('dtm_misc')->error('Error Saving PDF Thumbnail');
        }
      }catch (\Exception $e) {
          $imagick->destroy();
        \Drupal::logger('dtm_misc')->error('PDF To Image Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.. thanks

Comment: Would need to see an example of each; one file which is monochrome and one which is colour.

Comment: it's the same function but when the pdf file size is bigger than 1mb it gives a monochrome image.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the color profiles of the PDF themselves are the problem. You can try to get the current color space from the PDF and change it for your image.
Like: https://www.php.net/manual/de/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php#116565

Comment: it worked when i set the color space before loading the pdf

```
$imagick->SetColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution to the discussion above.

```
  public function convertPdfToImage($_pdf) {
    if (file_prepare_directory($this->thumbnailDirectory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
      try {
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $thumbFileName = $date->getTimestamp() . '.png';
        $imagick = new Imagick();
        $imagick->setResolution(50, 50);
        $imagick->setColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB); // SOLUTION
        $imagick->readImage($_pdf);
        $imagick->setIteratorIndex(0);
        $imagick->setImageFormat('png');
        $thumbFile = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($this->thumbnailDirectory . '/' . $thumbFileName);
        if ($imagick->writeImage($thumbFile)) {
          return $this->thumbnailDirectory . '/' . $thumbFileName;
        } else {
          \Drupal::logger('dtm_misc')->error('Error Saving PDF Thumbnail');
        }
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $imagick->destroy();
        \Drupal::logger('dtm_misc')->error('PDF To Image Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
```